# How to run a script in x64dbg

Tags: x64dbg

In the x64dbg manual is many [scripting commands](https://help.x64dbg.com/en/latest/commands/script/index.html) and other things, but nowhere in it is mentioned, how to launch a script.

So, my question is: *How to launch a script in x64dbg?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To launch a script, it has to be first *loaded* into x64dbg — *then* you will see it in the *Script* tab:
                                             [image]

Before loading a script, the content of this tab is empty:

[image]

You may load a script in any of the following ways:

1. Copy the *content* of your script into clipboard, then switch to the *Script* tab, and paste it with
   <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (NOT with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>).
2. The same, but using the context menu (*Load Script → Paste*):

   [image]
3. Switch to the `Script` tab, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, then select your script file.
4. The same, but using the context menu (*Load Script → Open...*) — as in the point 2.
5. Use the `scriptload` command with the path to your script file as an argument, for example

   ```
   scriptload "c:\Users\User\My Scripts\somescript.txt"
   ```

   Write it in the *Command:* box near the bottom left part of the x64dbg window and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

   [image]

After loading the script (with any of the previous methods), you will see it in the *Script* tab, and you may launch it with the <kbd>Space bar</kbd>, or by commands in the context menu:

[image]